# Cannot get Ruby on Rails to work on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation

Why is it so hard to get Ruby on Rails to work on a Mac? On Windows it is so easy but on my Mac, which I am now forced to use, it just doesn't want to play ball!

I cd into the project directory and run:

```
rails server
```

The the Terminal says:

```
You have requested:
  sqlite3 >= 0

The bundle currently has sqlite3 locked at 1.3.10.
Try running `bundle update sqlite3`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I run bundle update sqlite3 but then get:

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of     necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.      You may
need configuration options.

...

An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then run gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: That's kinda funny, because if you go to a rails conference,  You probably won't spot even one windows laptop - we all use macs.  (I think I might have seen a couple of Ubuntu systems)

Comment: Can you help me though? Xcode is already installed?

Comment: Come to think of it, this is a problem only encountered once when setting up a new laptop, so I have not tried for a really long time.  A google search for "os x xcode command line tools"  turns up more answers than you can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the logs, but I suggest you to check/install Xcode command line tools, which you can do with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Or by opening Xcode and installing them using GUI.